# Destrucción de sesión api de Google se puede desde un localhost o por no tener el protocolo de seguridad del candadito se recarga al dar atrás

Tags: api, hosting, localhost

he creado una aplicación-sita con inicio de api de Google, esta valida correctamente esta sesión   con correo de api de Google, al cerrar sesión y al iniciar redirige correctamente al destino indicado y programado pero el problema está en que después de darle logout y estar de nuevo en el índex le doy atrás y recarga como si la sección no se hubiera destruido, ya tiene el código para destruir la sesión y el token, esto no sucede con la sección validada desde la base de datos de MySQL, quiero saber si esto se debe a que lo estoy ejecutando desde  un XAMPP server ya q este no tiene protocolo http ni https, les agradezco sus aportes…
esto es lo que tengo en el archivo para destruir la session

```php
session_start();

// Desautorizar y revocar el token de acceso de Google
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $google_client = new Google_Client();
    $google_client->setClientId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com');
    $google_client->setClientSecret('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

    // Establecer el token de acceso almacenado en la API de Google Client Library
    $google_client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

    // Revocar el token de acceso de Google para cerrar la sesión de forma segura
    $google_client->revokeToken();

    // Eliminar el token de acceso de Google almacenado
    unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
}  

// Destruir la sesión local de tu aplicación (MySQL)
session_name('mysql_session');
session_start();
session_destroy();

// Redireccionar al inicio de sesión después de cerrar la sesión
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Recuerda el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask].